# ArgumentOutOfRangeException While trying to get the list of DataTable columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to get a list of my `DataTable` columns. The `DataTable` contains rows and columns when I am running the program so it is not `null`. This is the LINQ I am using:

```
List<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToList();
```

And I receive the following `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

> StartIndex cannot be less than zero.

**Stack trace:**

```
   at System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex)
   at Prospect.DataHelper.WriteDatatableToCsv(DataTable dt, String path, String fileName, String delimeter) in c:\xxxxxxxxxx\DataHelper.cs:line 400
   at Prospect.Contacts.<>c__DisplayClass21.<btnWrite_Click>b__20() in c:\xxxxxxxxxxx\Contacts.cs:line 684
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: You datatable `dt` may have no column

Comment: Check `if (dt.Columns.Count > 0)`

Comment: The code you've provided isn't the code in the stack trace. (Where's the call to `Remove`?) Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not very good with LINQ but why don't you try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("My table has: " + dt.Columns.Count + " columns.");  //just for testing
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
```